# Abnormalities when using SOR to solve the Poisson Equation

Tags: linear-solver, numerics, poisson

I am trying to solve the Poisson equation for Heterostructures using SOR. The equation to solve looks lik
[image]

I have discretized the Poisson equation using finite difference and my code is written in FORTRAN 90. I have the following questions.

1. Is it correct to apply SOR to above equation (I have discretized the 2nd order differential using FD method).
2. My solutions are depending on the initial guess. I get one potential profile when I take initial guess as zero and a different profile when I have a different initial guess based on charge neutrality. I am not sure why I am getting this.
3. My solutions are also depending on the relaxation parameter. For a relaxation of 1.45, I get "expected" results but for a relaxation of 1.90, my solver converges very rapidly (I get zero residual basically) and I get wrong results. Is this behavior expected and if so how do I make sure that I always get correct results?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) for typing your equations.

Comment: Is $V^\text{new}$ the unknown in your PDE? If so, it would help to write all the factors and terms grouped since they are not relevant to the question.